# Powershell script to extract logged errors

Tags: powershell

I have a lot of log files that I wish to extract the distinct error message from for a specific trace writer.

The log files are SharePoint ULS logs.

The headings are:
Timestamp
Process
TID
Area
Category
EventID
Level
Message
Correlation

So given a specific process name I want all distinct Messages.

If I was to use SQL I would write something like this:

select Distinct Message from  where Process like 'myprocessname'

I'd like to do this with powershell across a whole set of log files.

I believe the ULS log is tab or space delimited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be interested in Microsoft's [Log Parser](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=890cd06b-abf8-4c25-91b2-f8d975cf8c07&displaylang=en) which essentially lets you run SQL like statements across a set of log files.  You can also use this with Powershell.  Here are some links:

- [Analyze Web Stats with Log Parser](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2006.08.insidemsft.aspx)
- [Integrating Microsoft Log Parser in Windows Powershell](http://www.airedalez.net/?p=5)
- [Logparser and Powershell](http://event-horizon.eu/logparser-and-powershell)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the log file isn't too huge, you can read the contents in using Import-Csv like so:

```
$data = Import-Csv .\log.csv -Delimiter "`t"
```

I'm assuming the delimiter is tab since it is likely any message will contain spaces.  Once you have the log data you can use the standard PowerShell query operators like so:

```
$data | Where {$_.Process -eq 'processname.exe'} | Select Message -Unique
```

If the log file is huge (such that Import-Csv eats up too much memory) then I would either try using Log Parser or use a regex and parse the log, one line at a time.

Comment: would this approach work for multiple files, could i combine them into this?

Comment: Sure, just specify the files to Import-Csv e.g. `Import-Csv file1.csv,file2.csv,c:\temp\file3.csv ...`.